# ActionController::MethodNotAllowed (Only get, put, and delete requests are allowed.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error, ActionController::MethodNotAllowed (Only get, put, and delete requests are allowed.), when I try to submit a form.  My route looks like this,

admin.resources :email_launcher

and this is my form_for,

- form_for :email_launcher, :url => new_admin_email_launcher_path, :method => :get do |f|

This is not in a form but in the new view, and I'm using HAML. I've google searched all day on the error but never found anything of value. Any help would be great, thanks.

Here's my rake routes for admin_email_launcher

```
                          admin_email_launcher_index GET     /admin/email_launcher(.:format)                                                {:controller=>"admin/email_launcher", :action=>"index"}
                                                     POST    /admin/email_launcher(.:format)                                                {:controller=>"admin/email_launcher", :action=>"create"}
                            new_admin_email_launcher GET     /admin/email_launcher/new(.:format)                                            {:controller=>"admin/email_launcher", :action=>"new"}
                           edit_admin_email_launcher GET     /admin/email_launcher/:id/edit(.:format)                                       {:controller=>"admin/email_launcher", :action=>"edit"}
                                                     GET     /admin/email_launcher/:id(.:format)                                            {:controller=>"admin/email_launcher", :action=>"show"}
                                                     PUT     /admin/email_launcher/:id(.:format)                                            {:controller=>"admin/email_launcher", :action=>"update"}
                                                     DELETE  /admin/email_launcher/:id(.:format)                                            {:controller=>"admin/email_launcher", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Comment: Show the structure of your app: path for the controller and views, name of the view. Also run `rake routes` and show the part with admin_email_launcher.

Comment: the controller is email_launcher_controller and the view I have the form in is admin/email_launcher/new. The path to it is, new_admin_email_launcher_path.

Answer (score 0):

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :email_launcher
end
```

**admin/email_launchers_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @email_launcher = EmailLauncher.new
end
```

**admin/email_launcher/new**

```
<%= form_for([:admin,@email_launcher]) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end -%>
```

It will POST new email_launcher. 
Why do you need to GET the new action? You're already on the new page.

Comment: What if I have the output of the form, saving to a different table called AlertMailings. Would it be @email_launcher = AlertMailing.new?

Comment: The output of the form calls `create` method of email_launcher controller. In it you need to create new email launcher model object. It is by design. Why do you need new model?